# QByteArray get the address of nth element

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have the following code that I need to translate into qt from plain c++:

```
// txMessage and UserData are char arrays
memcpy(&txMessage[18], UserData, 8);
```

So my conversion is like this:

```
QByteArray txMessage;
txMessage.resize(26);
    :
    :
memcpy(&(txMessage.data()[18]), UserData, 8);
```

So this should work, but looks messy. I have to get the data pointer using the data() function and then reference element 18 with [18] and then take the address of that with &.

I looked through the whole QByteArray docs online and can't see another function that returns char* and operator [] only returns a temp variable, so can't address that. But there are so many options/functions for QByteArray maybe I missed something? Anyone found/got a better way to get the address of nth element in QByteArray?

**EDIT**
There are a few things that appear to be undocumented in QByteArray:

- char* data_ptr() - same issue though
- char* pointer  - says its for stl comparability, but can I use it / trust it?

Comment: `txMessage.data() + 18`, a bit better.

Comment: @Holt oh yeah.... that is a bit better :) +1

Comment: Did you try the `replace` method? `txMessage.replace(18, 8, UserData);`

Comment: @Holt marvelous!, I was looking in the wrong direction I think : ) ... stick that up as an answer and i'll mark it up if you want : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `replace` method instead:

```
txMessage.replace(18, 8, UserData, 8) ;
```

If you are using a Qt version less than 4.7, but your `UserData` variable is null-terminated, then simply:

```
txMessage.replace(18, 8, UserData) ;
```

Otherwize:

```
memcpy(txMessage.data() + 18, UserData, 8);
```